# Flutter - Include Widget on Condition

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to include a widget on when a condition is satisfied. What is the best way to do this?

```
Balance != null && Balance > 0
 ? Text(Balance, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red))
 : null,
```

But, I can't use null here!

Comment: So Use Empty `Container()` or Simply empty - `Text()`.

Answer (score 2):

As said anmol.majhail use a empty `Container()` or `Text()` empty then when the condition if false that show nothing .

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
Balance != null && Balance > 0
 ? Text(Balance, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red))
 : Container(),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Empty Container() or you can use a Visibility Widget for when the condition is true show widget and you can add animations etc.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html

Example

```
Visibility(
  visible: true //Default is true, you can add a Function or condition like Balance != null && Balance > 0,
  child: Text(Balance, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
),
```